# JavaScript Converting string values to hex

Tags: javascript

I have an array of string-encoded hex values.  I need to convert those strings to actual hex values and then be able to compare them (using standard less-than/greater-than/equals).  What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the JavaScript parseInt method to convert hex string values into their integer equivalent.

For example:

```
var value = parseInt("FF", 16);
if (value < 256) {
    // do something...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the parseInt function:

```
var n = parseInt("10", 16); // parse 10 as base 16 (hex).
```

-Oisin

Answer (score 2):

Use parseInt("0x"+ string) to transform your string value into a numeric one