# Javascript ascii string to hex byte array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am trying to convert an ASCII string into a byte array.

Problem is my code is converting from ASCII to a string array and not a Byte array:

```
var tx = '[86400:?]';
for (a = 0; a < tx.length; a = a + 1) {
    hex.push('0x'+tx.charCodeAt(a).toString(16));
}
```

This results in:

```
 [ '0x5b','0x38','0x36','0x30','0x30','0x30','0x3a','0x3f','0x5d' ]
```

But what I am looking for is:

```
[0x5b,0x38 ,0x30 ,0x30 ,0x30 ,0x30 ,0x3a ,0x3f,0x5d]
```

How can I convert to a byte rather than a byte string ?

This array is being streamed to a USB device:

```
device.write([0x5b,0x38 ,0x30 ,0x30 ,0x30 ,0x30 ,0x3a ,0x3f,0x5d])
```

And it has to be sent as one array and not looping sending device.write() for each value in the array.

Comment: `0x5b` isn't actually `0x5b`, but rather it's just a simple `int` with the value `91`. Save these as an int (`tx.charCodeAt(a)`) instead, and everything will be fine.

Comment: Numbers are numbers, and they're always stored in binary. If you want the hex representation, store it as a string (as you are now), or use `hex.push(tx.charCodeAt(a));`, which will store the ASCII codes, and use `.toString(16)` to convert to hex while printing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Converting string values to hex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527077/javascript-converting-string-values-to-hex)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A single liner :

```
   '[86400:?]'.split ('').map (function (c) { return c.charCodeAt (0); })
```

returns

```
    [91, 56, 54, 52, 48, 48, 58, 63, 93]
```

This is, of course, is an array of numbers, not strictly a "byte array". Did you really mean a "byte array"?

Split the string into individual characters then map each character to its numeric code.

Per your added information about `device.write` I found this :

> Writing to a device
>
> Writing to a device is performed using the write call in a device
>   handle. All writing is synchronous.
>
> device.write([0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0xff, 0xff]);

on https://npmjs.org/package/node-hid

Assuming this is what you are using then my array above would work perfectly well :

```
device.write('[86400:?]'.split ('').map (function (c) { return c.charCodeAt (0); }));
```

As has been noted the `0x` notation is just that, a notation. Whether you specify `0x0a` or `10` or `012` (in octal) the value is the same.

Comment: Thanks, yes it has to be a Hex byte array as the output is streamed to a usb device: device.write([0x5b,0x38 ,0x30 ,0x30 ,0x30 ,0x30 ,0x3a ,0x3f,0x5d]). So I really need a way of creating a hex-byte array !

Comment: a "byte array" is not "hex", it is often merely _presented_ in hex.

Comment: What environment are you running? node.js ?

Comment: Excellent, thanks, yes it is node.js and your googling was correct this is using node-hid. After some more testing, I now understand that it's not necessary to send the array in hex format so your solution works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
   function getBytes(str){
       let intArray=str.split ('').map (function (c) { return c.charCodeAt (0); });
       let byteArray=new Uint8Array(intArray.length);
       for (let i=0;i<intArray.length;i++)
         byteArray[i]=intArray[i];
       return byteArray;
   }
   device.write(getBytes('[86400:?]'));
```